# Jetpack Infinite Scrolling Showing different No. of Posts

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

Can somebody fix this please.

[image]

I am using Jetpack Infinite Scroll. The scroll is working fine but its the posts that are somewhat broken. See Image. My setting in WP Reading is 10 posts per page and I even added 'posts_per_page' => 10, in Jetpack functions.

Please help.. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your columns are different heights which is breaking the floats. One solution would be to set all the columns of the divs to the same height. Another one would be to use a jquery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Personally I would try to make all the columns equal height, as it would look tidier!

Comment: Yea... I changed the height and that works.. Though I needed to do a bit more CSS and removed the excerpt and heading. Added them via CSS on hover effect. Thanks for the help :)